# Закрыть окно или скрыть его

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки SignIn если авторизация прошла успешна то закрыть или скрыть данное окно (MainWindow.xaml)  используя при этом binding. 
C#,WPF,Messenger vk.com
https://github.com/ZorinIvanA/AU-2015-Eshonkhonov.git

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего использовать `Binding` на свойство `Visibility`. Трюк состоит в том, что

- нужно использовать `Mode="TwoWay"` (не знаю, почему именно; судя по всему, баг)
- нужно использовать `FallbackValue`, иначе если показать окно с пустым `DataContext`'ом, оно спрячется.

Код:

```
<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->
<Window x:Class="ТутВашНеймспейс.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BTV"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="IsVisible" Converter="{StaticResource BTV}"
                 Mode="TwoWay" FallbackValue="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
    </Window.Visibility>
</Window>
```

```
// MainVM.cs
class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return isVisible; }
        set { if (isVisible != value) { isVisible = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    // стандартная реализация INPC
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Тестовый код:

```
<!-- App.xaml -->
<!-- Не создавайте окно тут! -->
<Application x:Class="ТутВашНеймспейс.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

```
// App.xaml.cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var mainVM = new MainVM() { IsVisible = true };
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM };
        mainWindow.Show();

        await Task.Delay(3000);
        mainVM.IsVisible = false;

        await Task.Delay(3000);
        mainVM.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для закрытия диалоговых окон в MVVM использую вариант взятый http://blog.excastle.com/2010/07/25/mvvm-and-dialogresult-with-no-code-behind/

Реализовано в виде Attached Property

```
    public static class DialogCloser
    {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogResultProperty =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
              "DialogResult",
              typeof (bool?),
              typeof (DialogCloser),
              new PropertyMetadata(DialogResultChanged));

      private static void DialogResultChanged(
          DependencyObject d,
          DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          var window = d as Window;
          if (window != null)
          {
              window.DialogResult = e.NewValue as bool?;
              if (window.DialogResult != null)
                  window.Close();
          }
      }

      public static void SetDialogResult(Window target, bool? value)
      {
          target.SetValue(DialogResultProperty, value);
      }
    }
```

В ViewModel есть свойство. Оно у меня в базовом классе

```
    private bool? _dialogResult;

    public bool? DialogResult
    {
        get { return _dialogResult; }
        protected set
        {
            _dialogResult = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DialogResult");
        }
    }
```

В xaml диалогового окна задаю биндинг на него.

```
<Window ... attachedProperties:DialogCloser.DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult}" >
```

Теперь при установке внутри ViewModel свойства DialogResult в true/false окно закрывается и у окна фиксируется этот DialogResult

В лучших традициях MVVM и не нужно трогать code-behind

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно использовать библиотеку https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/

и добавить триггер на изменение свойства из viewModel. Когда значение свойства изменится, вызови метод из code-behind страницы, который её и закроет, как уже сделано в BnCancel_Click.

Примеры можешь найти в другом вопросе на SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819812/using-interaction-trigger-to-call-visibility-changed-method-wpf