# Создание ViewModel в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Нужно создавать VM в отдельном потоке. Пробовал два варианта:

1. Этот вариант тормозит главный поток

   ```
       public class MainVm : VmBase

       {
           public ButtonsVm ButtonsVm { get; private set; }


           public MainVm()
           {
               Init();
           }

           private async void Init()
           {
               var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

               ButtonsVm = await
                   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new ButtonsVm(), CancellationToken.None,
                       TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);
           }
       }
   ```
2. С этим вылетает exception

   ```
       public class MainVm : VmBase

       {
           public ButtonsVm ButtonsVm { get; private set; }


           public MainVm()
           {
               Init();
           }

           private async void Init()
           {
               await Task.Run(() => ButtonsVm = new ButtonsVm());
           }
       }
   ```

> Additional information: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as
>   the DependencyObject.

**UPDATE:** ButtonsVm в себе содержит еще около 15 VM, и обращается к модели которая работает с Entity, поэтому и хочется вынести ее создание в отдельный поток чтобы первое подключение к базе не подтормаживало программу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны создавать VM в главном потоке. А вот модельные объекты должны создаваться асинхронно, в отдельном потоке. И работа с ними тоже должна вестить асинхронно.

Ваша проблема не на этом уровне.

Comment: `VladD`, вижу вы человек опытный в `WPF`, не могли бы подсказать хороший пример реализации  сервиса создания дочерних и диалоговых окон в контексте паттерна `MVVM`? P.S. Могу создать отдельный вопрос под это дело )

Comment: @sp7: Где-то был вопрос на эту тему, сейчас поищу...

Comment: @sp7: Вот для немодальных окон: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455715/10105 (но там привязка VM к окну выполняется вручную).

Comment: `VladD`, хотелось что-то вроде `myWindowsSrv.ShowWindow(childVM);` т.е. вызвал сервис создания окон, передал ему `VM` и сервис на основе этой `VM` отобразил нужную `View`.

Comment: @sp7: Это ж классический Dependency Injection :) Напишите вопрос, да.

Comment: @sp7, и киньте сюда ссылку на вопрос, мне тоже интересно :)

Comment: `VladD`, ссылка на вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525998/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0-mvvm

Comment: @Lightness: Написал ответ на вопрос о сервисе.