# Как передавать результат комманды в другое окно?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Здравствуйте, такая задача: есть окно, в котором находятся фильтры для запроса на выборку предложений по жилью(выбор по цене, району, метражу и т д).

Хочу нажимать на кнопку искать, и вызывать окно, в котором будет список соответствующих предложений.

Значит команда, которая фильтрует список, в одном окне, а сам список в другом.

Но так оказывается не работает?

Запрос LINQ срабатывает, это точно, если список в том же окне, все работает.

DataContext один для обоих окон

Что у меня есть.

Кнопка

```
<Button  Command="{Binding ChercherCommand}" Content="Chercher" Width="60" Height="40" 
                         Background="FloralWhite"  Click="ChercherOffre_Click"
                         Margin="7,2,2,4" ToolTip="Chercher les offres">
```

Список, в другом окне

```
<ListView   Margin="4"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RechercheListe}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentOffre }" Width="140">
```

Вью Модель

```
ChercherCommand = new RelayCommand(GetRechercheListe);

private void GetRechercheListe()
        {
            RechercheListe = new ObservableCollection<Offre>(_ctx.Offres.Where
                (o => (o.Prix >= CurrentDemande.Prix_de && o.Prix <= CurrentDemande.Prix_a) 
                && o.RegionId == CurrentDemande.RegionId && o.TypeId == CurrentDemande.TypeId &&
                (o.Etage >= CurrentDemande.Etage_de && o.Etage <= CurrentDemande.Etage_a) && 
                (o.Nombre_Etages >= CurrentDemande.NombreEtages_de && o.Nombre_Etages <= CurrentDemande.NombreEtages_a)&&
                (o.Surface >= CurrentDemande.Surface_de && o.Surface <= CurrentDemande.Surface_a) &&
                (o.Pieces >= CurrentDemande.Pieces_de && o.Pieces <= CurrentDemande.Pieces_a)));
            FirePropertyChanged("RechercheListe");

            foreach (Offre o in RechercheListe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }
        }
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Отформатируйте ваш код.

Comment: спасибо, я еще не научилась здесь форматировать, чтобы код виден был, есть какая.то кнопка для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему вы решили что `DataContext` у них один? Если честно в вашем  коде я не вижу вообще что бы где-то вызывалось новое окно, только одна фильтрация с использованием `Linq`.

В общем виде решение данной задачи будет примерно следующим:

1. При нажатии на кнопку **Искать**, срабатывает команда, которая ассоциирована с данной кнопкой и подготавливаются отфильтрованные данные.

   ```
   var filteredData = _ctx.Offres.Where(p => ваш фильтр).ToList();
   ```
2. Так же у вас должен быть реализован некий сервис модальных/немодельных окон, например, у которого есть метод `ShowView` (или что-то в этом духе) задача этого метода одна - принять на вход `ViewModel` и на основании этой модели отобразить `View`. Реализовать подобный сервис можно по-разному, написать все самому, взять готовую реализацию, например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525998/16781), либо воспользоваться [одним](https://github.com/catel/catel) из `WPF` framework'ов в котором это уже сделали за вас.

   ```
   public interface IWindowSrv 
   {
       bool ShowView(ViewModelBase vm);
   }
   ```
3. Кроме того, необходимо реализовать `ViewModel` дочернего окна, которая должна принимать в конструкторе коллекцию отфильтрованных данных.

   ```
   public class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
   { 
       public ChildViewModel(IEnumerable<MyData> data) { }
   }
   ```
4. После того, как все будет готово, можно создавать дочерние окно и передавать в него данные:

   ```
   private void ShowChildView()
   {
        // Фильтруем данные
        var filteredData = _ctx.Offres.Where(p => ваш фильтр).ToList();

        // Создаем ViewModel
        var vm = new ChildViewModel(filteredData);

        // Отображаем дочернее окно
        var result = _windowSrv.ShowView(vm);
   }
   ```

Comment: Точно, надо же передать список в дочернее окно, вот это я тупень, ну что поделаешь :) сделала, что вызов окна происходит при вызове комманды, так работает, надеюсь это правильно и не противоречит правилам Mvvm... по правилам вроде вьюмодель не должна знать о вью? или это не так?

Comment: public void GetRechercheListe()
  {
   
   ЗДЕСЬ ФИЛЬТР

   var vm = new ChercherOffreViewModel(RechercheListe);
   ChercherOffreWindow win = new ChercherOffreWindow();
   win.DataContext = vm;
   win.ShowDialog();
     }

Comment: `по правилам вроде вьюмодель не должна знать о вью? ` а где вы здесь увидели, что `VM` знает о `View`?

Comment: я создаю окно, для этого во вьюмодель делаю using на вью... вот и получается, что вью модель знает о вью

Comment: Дак а зачем вы так делаете? За создание `View` должен отвечать сервис модальных/немодельных окон, в ответе про это сказано.