# WPF&MVVM: привязка к окну комманды, определённой в каталоге на уровень выше

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Этот вопрос является продолжением обсуждений в комментариях к [WPF: Как правильно с точки зрения концепции MVVM вызывать новое окно командой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/727749/218063). Новая задача такая: нужно сделать кнопку для завершения приложения, а также реализовать возможность закрывать окно сочетанием клавиш (первая кнопка уже имеется в каждом окне - "Красный крестик", а любое приложение закрывается сочетанием `Alt+F4`, но это, что называется, самый простой пример для дальнейшего усложнения).

Закрытие окна сочетанием клавиш уже реализовано:

```
public partial class MainWindowView : Window {

    public ICommand ExitCommand { get; }

    public MainWindowView() {
        InitializeComponent();
        ExitCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => Close());
}
```

XAML (Всё, что не имеет отношения, убрано):

```
<Window x:Class="Example.Views.MainWindowView"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example">

    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ExitCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                    Gesture="Ctrl+E"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

Все View хранятся в папке `Views`, класс `DelegateCommand` - в корне проекта.

Первая попытка привязать событие к кнопке выглядит так:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:MainWindowView.ExitCommand"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

В этом случае IDE пишет, что имени `MainWindowView` в пространсве имён `clr-namespace:Example` нет. Так-то оно так: `MainWindowView` кранится в папке `Views`, но как приведёно ниже, работать тоже не будет:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
  <CommandBinding Command="local:Views.MainWindowView.ExitCommand"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Тогда я попробовал задать другое пространсво имён:

```
<Window x:Class="Example.Views.MainWindowView"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Example.Views"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example">

    <Window.CommandBindings>
       <CommandBinding Command="views:MainWindowView.ExitCommand"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
```

В этот раз пишет, что значение `value` имеет значение `null`.

Что следует сделать?

Comment: Ну а `{Binding ExitCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}` не работает что ли?

Comment: @Андрей, нет, тоже пробовал. `Невозможно настроить Binding через свойство Command типа CommandBinding. Binding можно настроить только через DependencyProperty объекта DependencyObject`.

Comment: Подождите, а зачем вам вообще нужен `CommandBinding`? У вас же собственная команда, которой вы уже присвоили метод `Execute` в коде, `CommandBinding` нужен для встроенных в WPF команд, которым нужно установить обработчик

Comment: Вы понимаете вообще что делает `CommandBinding`?

Comment: @Андрей, очень поверхностно. Понимаю только то, что эта привязка устанавливает взаимодействие окна(приёмник) и класса, где определена команда (источник).

Comment: В WPF есть набор штатных команд, типа `New`, `Open`, `Undo` и т.п., у них не определено действие, которое будет выполняться при вызове команды. CommandBinding позволяет настроить это действие. Вы используете свою реализацию команд, в конструкторе передаете метод, который будет вызван при вызове команды. CommandBinding вам не нужен.

Comment: @Андрей, Я правильно Вас понял, что если все команды - свои собственные, то весь блок `<Window.CommandBindings><CommandBinding Command="..."/></Window.CommandBindings>` не нужен и достаточно к кнопке привязать `Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите. Вы всё перепутали.

У вас есть два варианта - использовать самописную реализацию команды или использовать команды из штатного набора WPF.

1. Первый вариант у вас описан и он у вас уже работает.

   Вы имеете какую-то реализацию интерфейса ICommand и создаете команду:

   ```
   public partial class MainWindowView : Window {

       public ICommand ExitCommand { get; }

       public MainWindowView() {
           InitializeComponent();
           ExitCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => Close());
       }
   }
   ```

   Потом уже в XAML вы вешаете команду на сочетание клавиш:

   ```
   <Window.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ExitCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                   Gesture="Ctrl+E"/>
   </Window.InputBindings>
   ```

   Всё, это работает как нужно.
2. Второй вариант, воспользуемся командой `Close` из поставки WPF (список всех команд, входящих в поставку см. под ответом)

   Установим команде обработчик:

   ```
   <Window.CommandBindings>
       <CommandBinding Command="Close" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
   </Window.CommandBindings>
   ```

   Код обработчика:

   ```
   private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
       Close();
   }
   ```

   Вешаем команду на сочетание клавиш:

   ```
   <Window.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Command="Close"
                   Gesture="Ctrl+E"/>
   </Window.InputBindings>
   ```

   Готово!

Смешивать эти два способа не нужно.

---

Стандартные классы с командами WPF:

1. [ApplicationCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [NavigationCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.navigationcommands(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [EditingCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. [ComponentCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.componentcommands(v=vs.110).aspx)
5. [MediaCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.input.mediacommands(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за объяснения, очень много прояснилось! Осталось только разобраться, как эти же команды прицепить к кнопкам. `Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"` как и `Command="{ExitCommand}"`-то не работают что-то...

Comment: `{Binding ExitCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}` же

Comment: Отлично! Одной проблемой меньше! Как не хватает Ваших объяснений в уроках по WPF...