# C# WPF закрыть ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

Запускаю окно асинхронно в другом потоке

```
await window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => window.ShowDialog());
```

Как его закрыть?

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Во время закрытия окна нельзя установить для Visibility значение Visible или вызвать Show, ShowDialog, Close или WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle."

Comment: А как вы его сейчас закрывать пробуете и как закрыть хотите? Покажите больше релевантного кода и больше описания ситуации.

Comment: @Kromster использую пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/730217/276534

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. Т.е. каждый вопрос должен быть самодостаточен.

Comment: @Kromster я посчитал его самодостаточным

Comment: Когда исключение возникает? Похоже что вы пытаетесь закрыть окно в то время, когда оно уже начало процесс закрытия.

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, помогло, спасибо