# ViewModel не обрабатывает диалоговое окно в MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

Всем привет. я использую в своем WPF-приложении паттерн MVVM. я делаю логику взаимодействия между окнами по примеру [WPF: Как правильно с точки зрения концепции MVVM вызывать новое окно командой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727749/wpf-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-mvvm-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9) и https://github.com/bakulev/MVVM_OpenNewWindowMinimalExample. Есть сервис, который запускает вспомогательные окна с помощью async/await.

```
public class DisplayRootRegistry
{
    Dictionary<Type, Type> vmToWindowMapping = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    public void RegisterWindowType<VM, Win>() where Win : Window, new() where VM : class
    {
        var vmType = typeof(VM);
        if (vmType.IsInterface)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot register interfaces");
        if (vmToWindowMapping.ContainsKey(vmType))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"Type {vmType.FullName} is already registered");
        vmToWindowMapping[vmType] = typeof(Win);
    }

    public void UnregisterWindowType<VM>()
    {
        var vmType = typeof(VM);
        if (vmType.IsInterface)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot register interfaces");
        if (!vmToWindowMapping.ContainsKey(vmType))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"Type {vmType.FullName} is not registered");
        vmToWindowMapping.Remove(vmType);
    }

    public Window CreateWindowInstanceWithVM(object vm)
    {
        if (vm == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("vm");
        Type windowType = null;

        var vmType = vm.GetType();
        while (vmType != null && !vmToWindowMapping.TryGetValue(vmType, out windowType))
            vmType = vmType.BaseType;

        if (windowType == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"No registered window type for argument type {vm.GetType().FullName}");

        var window = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(windowType);
        window.DataContext = vm;
        return window;
    }


    Dictionary<object, Window> openWindows = new Dictionary<object, Window>();
    public void ShowPresentation(object vm)
    {
        if (vm == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("vm");
        if (openWindows.ContainsKey(vm))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("UI for this VM is already displayed");
        var window = CreateWindowInstanceWithVM(vm);
        window.Show();
        openWindows[vm] = window;
    }

    public void HidePresentation(object vm)
    {
        Window window;
        if (!openWindows.TryGetValue(vm, out window))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("UI for this VM is not displayed");
        window.Close();
        openWindows.Remove(vm);
    }

    public async Task ShowModalPresentation(object vm)
    {
        var window = CreateWindowInstanceWithVM(vm);
        window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        await window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => window.ShowDialog());
    }

}
```

Далее в App.xaml.cs регистрируются все ViewModel и запускается главное View:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public DisplayRootRegistry displayRootRegistry = new DisplayRootRegistry();
        AnalyzerViewModel mainWindowViewModel;

        public App()
        {
            displayRootRegistry.RegisterWindowType<AnalyzerViewModel, MainWindow>();
            displayRootRegistry.RegisterWindowType<SavePartViewModel, SavePart>();
        }

        protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            mainWindowViewModel = new AnalyzerViewModel();

            await displayRootRegistry.ShowModalPresentation(mainWindowViewModel);

            Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Внутри MainWindowViewModel(AnalyzerViewModel) запускается View SavePart c Помощью класса OpenDialogWindowCommand:

```
public abstract class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    protected Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public MyCommand(Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public MyCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public abstract void Execute(object parameter)
    ;
}

public class OpenDialogWindowCommand: MyCommand
{
    AnalyzerViewModel mainViewModel;

    public OpenDialogWindowCommand(AnalyzerViewModel mainVM, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null) : base (canExecute)
    {
        mainViewModel = mainVM;
    }

    public override async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var displayRootRegistry = (Application.Current as App).displayRootRegistry;

        var savePartViewModel = new SavePartViewModel();
        await  displayRootRegistry.ShowModalPresentation(savePartViewModel);
        mainViewModel.AA_SearchText = savePartViewModel.TextValue;
    }
}

public class AnalyzerViewModel : BasicViewModel,INotifyPropertyChanged  {
    //команда "сохранить деталь"
    private OpenDialogWindowCommand cmdSavePart;
    public OpenDialogWindowCommand CmdSavePart
    {
        get
        {
            return cmdSavePart ??
                (cmdSavePart = new OpenDialogWindowCommand(this, (obj) =>
                {
                    DGPartItem temp = obj as DGPartItem;
                    return temp != null && temp.IsSaved == false;
                }
                ));
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в следующем, из диалогового SavePartViewModel я могу передать информацию в главный ViewModel. Но при этом в диалоговом SavePartViewModel созданные мною команды не обрабатываются. Если поставить breakpoint внутри обработчика, то в него VS попадает только после закрытия диалогового окна. В чем здесь проблема и как её можно решить?

SavePartViewModel.cs:

```
public class SavePartViewModel: BasicViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string textValue;
    public string TextValue
    {
        get { return textValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value.ToString().Length == 150)
                AlertMessage = "Не более 150 символов";
            textValue = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("TextValue");
        }
    }
}
```

TextValue возвращает значение для главного ViewModel, т.е. привязка работает, но при этом предупреждающее сообщение не выводит, когда длина текста достигает 150 символов. Я не знаю как внутри работает async/await, вероятно причина в этом.

Comment: Там долго читать и разбираться, вы можете привести в вопросе все, что нужно для воспроизведения вашей проблемы?

Comment: добавил пример кода

Comment: Залейте на гитхаб и дайте ссылку, на живом проекте готов посмотреть (тестовый пример можно набросать), а сидеть здесь разбирать тонны кода, к сожалению, нет. Я на первой своей работе такую штуку полностью с нуля сам написал. Да, я конечно посмотрел примеры и идею, но всё написал сам без копипаста.

Comment: @ФёдорДудников, async await внутри работает так: https://imgur.com/AUflfeT

Comment: @CasperSC , вот небольшой пример https://github.com/FedorrV/MVVM_WPF_Example. DialogWindowViewModel возвращает значение главному VM, но при этом сам не обрабатывает своё View

Comment: @ФёдорДудников, кстати, вот посмотрите такой пример. Там используется интересный приём, который подсмотрел в Prism: https://bitbucket.org/CasperSC/mvvmopeningthewindowexample/src/master/

Comment: Вот ещё здесь много можно посмотреть: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправляет ошибку добавление `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_OpenNewWindowMinimalExample.Views.DialogWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_OpenNewWindowMinimalExample.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DialogWindow" Height="100" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Диалоговое окно успешно открыто!" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBlock}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!