# Как создать новое окно при изменении свойства в ViewModel MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Можно ли вообще при обновлении свойства во ViewModel создать новое окно, в котором будут выводится данные из этого же свойства? Если да, то каким образом?

Comment: Вывод данных из свойства - это элементарно, просто задаете `DataContext` окну и открываете. А вот как открыть новое окно по правилам MVVM, вот ту есть небольшая загвоздка, ведь окно, это `View` слой, а по правилам MVVM мы не должны знать про `View` в `ViewModel` и наоборот. Поэтому посмотрите, как правильно в рамках MVVM открывать окна (например [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727774/220553)), тогда все остальные ваши вопросы решатся просто.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это не совсем то. Как выводить данные с VM в окно я знаю. Вопрос состоит в другом. При изменении свойства во VM срабатывает ивент PropertyChanged. Можно как-то отловить этот ивент во View не прибегая к Binding и открыть новое окно?

Comment: `Как выводить данные с VM в окно я знаю.` - как? В MVVM вы не можете просто взять и написать `new SomeWindow() {DataContext = this.Prop }.Show();`, это будет нарушением подхода. Как правильно, я вам ссылку дал. Также и событие `PropertyChanged`, View не должен знать про него что либо (почти), ведь View это чисто UI, чисто взаимодействие с пользователем, не более. По этому я вам и сказал, ваш вопрос весь сводится к тому, как правильно открыть окно, а уже в VM вы ловите событие изменение (или в `set`) свойства пишете логику открытия окна с нужным `DataContext`.