# Не выполняется команда в диалоговом окне. MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

При открытии диалогового окна для добавления элемента в бд команда add просто не реагирует.
Метод окрытия:

```
        public ViewModelCommand OpenAddNewShopWindow
        {
            get
            {
                return openAddNewShopWindow ?? new ViewModelCommand(obj =>
                {
                    OpenAddShopWindowMethod();
                   
                });
                 
            }
        }
        private void OpenAddShopWindowMethod()
        {
            AddNewShopWindow newShopWindow = new AddNewShopWindow();
            SetCenterPositionAndOpen(newShopWindow);

        }
```

Метод добавления:

```
public ViewModelCommand AddNewShop
        {
            get
            {
                return addNewShop ?? new ViewModelCommand(obj =>
                {
                    Window wnd = obj as Window;
                    string result = ""; 
                    if (ShopName == null || ShopName.Replace(" ", "").Length == 0)
                    {
                        SetRedBlockControll(wnd, "NameBlock");
                        ShowMessageToUser(result);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = AdminFunctiones.CreateShop(ShopName);
                        ShowMessageToUser(result);
                        wnd.Close();
                    }
                }
                );

            }
        }
```

Кнопка добавления в xaml:

```
Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add shop" Command="{Binding AddNewShop}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Background="#FFE5C6C6"/>
```

[image: форма окна:]

Но когда я перенес текст блок Name и кнопку добавления на главную страницу (т.е. просто убрал диалогjвое окно), команда выполняется.
Логика добавления элемента и окрытия окна содеражатся в одной viewmodel, дата контексты к окнам подключены.

Comment: Передача компонента View в команду как параметр является грубым нарушением MVVM. Если кнопка должна делать что-то только во View, используйте обработчик события Click и пишите код-бихайнд. Другими словами, вы не можете открывать окна из ViewModel, это всё нарушает MVVM, отсюда и проблемы. Но [нужны ли окна?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727774/373567 про окна в MVVM

Comment: Как и сказали выше, у вас нарушение MVVM, ибо вы используете UI элементы (окно) в ViewModel слое, когда как при MVVM подходе, у вас должна быть максимально развязанная архитектура, где UI не зависит от других слоев, даже не знает что-либо про них; ViewModel не знает про UI, а Model не знает про V и VM. Если всеж хотите решить то, что написали, то первый тогда вопрос - где `DataContext` у открываемого окна? Для правильной привязки нужны 3 вещи: 1. `DataContext` на класс с данными. 2. В классе данных публичное свойство. 3. В XAML указание имени этого публичного свойства через `Binding`.