# Получить значение параметра из MainViewModel в любой другой ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalonia

В MainViewModel есть параметр **_buttonsEnabled**, привязанный во view ко всем нужным кнопкам. Также есть второе окно LoginPanel, в котором происходит регистрация пользователя. Пользователя всего 2:

1. Админ, которому доступны все кнопки
2. user, которому некоторые кнопки недоступны

Окно LoginPanel вызываю из MainViewModel по кнопке:

```
[RelayCommand]
public void LoginUser()
 {
    var loginPanel = new LoginPanel();
    loginPanel.Show();
 }
```

У LoginPanel есть своя LogicPanelViewModel, в которой идет логика проверки логина и пороля из БД.
И в зависимости от пользователя я хочу переключать **_buttonsEnabled** в MainViewModel.

Проблема: Как получить доступ к **_buttonsEnabled** из другой ViewModel?
Видел решение, в котором нужно передать в конструктор класс основного окна, но это решение скорее всего реализовано без использования MVVM.

Comment: А не должно быть два разных view для администратора и для пользователя?

Comment: `Видел решение, в котором нужно передать в конструктор класс` - передавать окна, нельзя, это нарушение MVVM, ибо ViewModel знает про View слой, чего быть не должно. В вашем вопросе сейчас также есть это нарушение, ибо `LoginPanel` - это "окно", то есть View, ну а команда относится к ViewModel. Отвечая на ваш вопрос (передать VM в другую VM) - через конструктор, связывать VM слои можно, и даже порой нужно, то есть `var vm = new SomeViewModel(this);`, где `this` это `MainViewModel`. Но тут стоит подумать о вынесении логики за пределы VM.

Comment: Например, вы можете использовать [сообщения](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) от MVVMToolkit, благодаря которым будете оповещать главную VM, меняя ее свойство. Или вы можете создать отдельный сервис, который будет отвечать за окна, их открывать, и уже его передавать в нужные VM. Почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727774/220553). Ну а так, в любом случае, вам надо абстрагироваться от View слоев, оперируя только VM.

Comment: Пытался сделать так: var loginPanel = new LoginPanel(this); Определял конструктор LoginPanel, принимающий MainViewModel. Но вылезала ошибка, так не определялось что такое this. Нужно в Code-behind файле менять конструктор? Потому что в loginpanelviewmodel данного конструктора нет.
Я оперирую только лишь двумя vm. К view я просто привязываю _buttonsEnabled. Хотелось бы обойтись малой кровью, и не использовать messenger.

Comment: `buttonsEnabled` - кнопка? Её состоянием, как правило, управляет тоже VM, а если быть точнее - команда, к которой она привязана. Как выше сказал @EvgeniyZ - выносите логику из VM в сервис/класс/etc., передавайте в VM не VM или V, а сервис, при этом он должен быть Singleton

Comment: <Button isEnabled={Binding ButtonsEnabled}" Content="Отчет" ></Button>
Все, что мне нужно, это при успешной авторизации в LginPanelViewModel, переключить _buttonsEnabled переменную, которая находится в MainViewModel