# Открытие второго окна в паттерне MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Как ПРАВИЛЬНО реализовать открытие второго окна из кнопки на первом окне с использованием паттерна MVVM?
На сети конкретного примера я не нашел, а во многих проектах открытие окна идет нарушая принципы данного паттерна...

Comment: Что представляет собой это окно?

Comment: @Андрей: первое окно стандартное, где реализован основной функционал. Второе окно должно открываться как диалоговое, где пользователь выбирает требуемые параметры.

Comment: Просто добавьте в обработчик клика по кнопке: `var window = new ChildWindow(); window.DataContext = ((IMainVm)DataContext).ChildVm; window.Show();`

Comment: Можно еще, конечно, сделать как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/218063), но мне это не совсем нравится

Comment: @Андрей: Можно подробней про ваш код?
Не совсем понял, что у вас выступает в качестве ChildWindow и IMainVm...

Comment: Не нарушая принципов, будет вызов окна прямо по месту, т.е. во вьюхе. Загружаем окно, загружаем к нему вьюмодель, связываем их между собой, передаем какие нужно данные во вьюмодель, делаем видимым это дочернее окно. Про это вам выше сказал @Андрей

Comment: Вот у меня имеется VM - SettingsWindowVM и View - SettingsWindow.
Вызов окна осуществляется из HeaderVM.
Раньше реализовано было все просто, но не правильно
SetWindow = new SettingsWindow();
            SetWindow.ShowDialog();

а содержимое данные для окна были привязаны в xaml
<Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:SettingsWindowVM/>

Comment: И почему это не правильно?

Comment: @Bulson: просматривая некоторые форумы, многие говорили, что такой подход не правильный, мол не нужно вьюмодели так напраямую работать с вьюшкой, поэтому и спросил. Что бы в дальнейшем правильно реализовывать подобные вещи...

Comment: В "правильных" подходах для отображения нового окна используют привязки и/или разные абстрактные менеджеры внутри VM

Comment: Явным признаком неправильности служит знаете что? Это когда вам в класс VM для какого-то действия требуется добавить что-то из этого: `using System.Windows;` или даже `using System.Windows.Controls;`, т.е. когда вам нужно во вьюмодели напрямую поработать с классами граф.интерфейса. В этот самый момент начинайте бить себя по рукам.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, в вашем случае: `var window = new SettingsWindow(); window.DataContext = new SettingsWindowVM(); window.Show();` Единственный минус - здесь зависимость от конкретной реализации VM, но это, скорее всего, незначительный минус для простых приложений - сомневаюсь, что вы имеете возможность привязывать разные VM к одному окну. Вот вы можете избавиться от сильной связности, если будете привязываться к интерфейсу, который будут реализовывать ваши VM, а конкретная реализация будет поступать из свойства (определенного в интерфейсе) главной VM. Ну или из IoC-контейнера.

Comment: Т.е. в моем примере вы создаете интерфейс: `interface IHeaderVM { ISettingsVM SettingsVM { get; } }`, а сама главная VM реализует его, например так: `class HeaderVM : IHeaderVM { public ISettingsVM SettingsVM => new SettingsWindowVM(); }` (тут уж сами определитесь создавать `SettingsWindowVM` при каждом запросе новую или один раз создать и всегда отдавать этот экземпляр). `SettingsWindowVM` естественно должна реализовывать `ISettingsVM`

Comment: И тогда пример превращается в: `var window = new SettingsWindow(); window.DataContext = ((IHeaderVM)DataContext).SettingsVM; window.Show();` Всё красиво, программируем на уровне интерфейсов, сильной связности нет

Comment: @Андрей: спасибо большое, буду пробовать реализовать

Comment: Хорошая статья на эту тему. WPF and Inversion of Control. Use Inversion of Control to decouple views and viewmodels in WPF. By Patrick Steele10/01/2011 https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2011/10/01/WPF-and-Inversion-of-Control.aspx?Page=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если разберетесь в коде, то попробуйте **DialogService**. Простите, нет много времени еще более подробно ответить.

Пользоваться можно так:

```
                //просто какие-то входные данные
                var settingsWindowRequest = new SettingsLocalEvent() {};

                //вид диалога, это UserControl
                var view = new ChangeSettingsView(settingsWindowRequest, this);

                //диалог сервис
                var dialogService = new DialogService();

                //вызов диалога
                dialogService.ShowDialog<NewSettingsLocalEvent>(
                    view, 
                    //пояснения к SetNewSettings см ниже
                    newSettings => SetNewSettings(newSettings), 
                    throwIfNullResult: false,
                    //imageUri - это моя отсебятина от лени, можно удалять из исходников
                    imageUri: new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Red.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                    );



<UserControl x:Class="Xyz.View.ChangeSettingsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xyz.View"
         xmlns:lctrl="clr-namespace:Xyz.LocalControls"
         xmlns:mvvm="Sborka_S_Ishodnikami_I_Sootvetstvuyushij_Namespace"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="390" d:DesignWidth="530">

    <mvvm:DialogService.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="mvvm:DialogContainer" BasedOn="{StaticResource OkCancelDialogStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Title}" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="530"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="500"/>
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="Настройки"/>
        </Style>
    </mvvm:DialogService.ContainerStyle>

</UserControl>
```

В приведенном выше коде вбейте правильный `Sborka_S_Ishodnikami_I_Sootvetstvuyushij_Namespace`. Вот пример стиля **OkCancelDialogStyle**:

```
        <Style x:Key="OkCancelDialogStyle" TargetType="mvvm:DialogContainer">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="mvvm:DialogContainer">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <controls:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <Border Background="WhiteSmoke" MinHeight="50" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                        BorderBrush="LightGray"
                                        BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                                        >
                                        <StackPanel 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Height="24"
                                        Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                        >
                                            <Button Content="OK" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding OkCommand}" MinWidth="60" Margin="0,0,4,0" />
                                            <Button Content="Отмена" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" IsCancel="True" MinWidth="60" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </controls:BusyIndicator>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

На всякий случай и это:

```
public partial class ChangeSettingsView : UserControl
{
    public ChangeSettingsView(SettingsLocalEvent request, object viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }


}
```

Так же во ViewModel можно реализрвать интерфейс **IDialogCloseable** (`IDialogCloseable<TResponse>`), тогда будет event:

```
public event DialogCloseEvent<TResponse> DialogClose = delegate { };
```

Можно во ViewModel прописать такой метод:

```
    protected void RaiseDialogClose(object sender, bool? dialogResult, TResponse result)
    {
        DialogClose(sender, new DialogCloseEventArgs<TResponse>(dialogResult, result));
    }
```

Тогда, например, в какой-то команде (ICommand) по клику кнопки OK можно будет вызвать этот event:

```
    private void ExecuteOk(object input)
    {
        RaiseDialogClose(this, true, new NewSettingsLocalEvent()
            {

            }
            );
    }
```

Кстати, в самом начале кода в данном ответе, где написано "пользоваться можно так", там при вызове диалога есть такой параметр: `newSettings => SetNewSettings(newSettings)`. Если не ошибаюсь, то этот Func как раз и вызывается при нажатии OK в диалоге. Здесь *SetNewSettings* это просто какой-то метод, суть в том, что он вызовется при нажатии ОК (опять же, если не ошибаюсь).

---

**исходники**

```
[StyleTypedProperty(Property="ContainerStyleProperty", StyleTargetType=typeof(DialogContainer))]
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public static Style GetContainerStyle(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Style)obj.GetValue(ContainerStyleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetContainerStyle(DependencyObject obj, Style value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ContainerStyleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainerStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ContainerStyle", 
            typeof(Style), 
            typeof(DialogService),
            new PropertyMetadata(null)
            {
                CoerceValueCallback = ContainerStylePropertyCoerce
            }
        );

    private static object ContainerStylePropertyCoerce(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var style = baseValue as Style;
        if (style != null)
        {
            if (style.TargetType != typeof(DialogContainer))
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }

            return style;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void ShowDialog(FrameworkElement view)
    {
        this.ShowDialog<object>(view, (DialogCallback<object>)null);
    }

    public void ShowDialog<T>(FrameworkElement view, Action<T> onSuccess, bool throwIfNullResult = false, Uri imageUri = null)
    {
        this.ShowDialog<T>(
            view,
            (dr, result) =>
            {
                if (dr == true && onSuccess != null) onSuccess(result);
            },
            throwIfNullResult,
            imageUri
        );
    }

    public void ShowDialog<T>(FrameworkElement view, DialogCallback<T> callback, bool throwIfNullResult = false, Uri imageUri = null)
    {
        var container = new DialogContainer(view);

        if (imageUri != null)
            container.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(imageUri);

        var dialogResult = container.ShowDialog();

        if (callback != null)
        {
            T result = default(T);

            if (dialogResult == true)
            {
                if (throwIfNullResult && container.DialogContainerResult == null)
                {
                    throw new NullReferenceException("DialogContainerResult");
                }

                if (container.DialogContainerResult != null)
                {

                    if (container.DialogContainerResult is T)
                    {
                        result = (T)container.DialogContainerResult;
                    }
                }
            }

            callback(dialogResult, result);
        }
    }

    public MessageBoxResult ShowMessage(
        string message, 
        string caption = null, 
        MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OK, 
        MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.None, 
        MessageBoxResult defaultResult = MessageBoxResult.None, 
        MessageBoxOptions options = MessageBoxOptions.None
        )
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(message, caption, button, icon, defaultResult, options);
    }
}

public delegate void DialogCallback<T>(bool? dialogResult, T parameter);

public interface IDialogService
{
    void ShowDialog(FrameworkElement view);
    void ShowDialog<T>(FrameworkElement view, Action<T> onSuccess, bool throwIfNullResult = false, Uri imageUri = null);
    void ShowDialog<T>(FrameworkElement view, DialogCallback<T> callback, bool throwIfNullResult = false, Uri imageUri = null);

    MessageBoxResult ShowMessage(
        string message,
        string caption = null,
        MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OK,
        MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.None,
        MessageBoxResult defaultResult = MessageBoxResult.None,
        MessageBoxOptions options = MessageBoxOptions.None
        );
}


public class DialogContainer : Window
{
    static DialogContainer()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(DialogContainer),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DialogContainer))
            );
    }

    //private IDialogCloseable _closeable = null;

    private static Style _GetBaseStyle;
    private static Style GetBaseStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return _GetBaseStyle ?? (_GetBaseStyle = Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(DialogContainer)) as Style);
        }
    }

    internal DialogContainer(FrameworkElement view, Window owner = null)
    {

        Content = view;

        this.Owner = owner
            ?? Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Where(x => x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault()
            ?? Application.Current.MainWindow;

        WindowStartupLocation = owner == null                  
            ? System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
            : System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

        if (view != null)
        {
            var containerStyle = DialogService.GetContainerStyle(view);
            if (containerStyle != null)
            {
                if (containerStyle.BasedOn == null)
                {
                    containerStyle.BasedOn = GetBaseStyle;
                }

                Style = containerStyle;
            }

            CloseableDescriptor = GetFirstIDialogCloseable(view, view.DataContext);

            var dataContextBinding = new Binding()
            {
                Source = view,
                Path = new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty)
            };

            SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, dataContextBinding);
        }
    }

    private DynamicCloseableDescriptor CloseableDescriptor = null;

    private DynamicCloseableDescriptor GetFirstIDialogCloseable(params object[] items)
    {
        var descriptors = from x in items
                          where x != null 
                          let icloseable = x.GetType()
                              .GetInterfaces()
                              .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDialogCloseable<>))
                              .FirstOrDefault()
                          where icloseable != null
                          select new DynamicCloseableDescriptor(this, x, icloseable);

        var target = descriptors.FirstOrDefault();
        return target;

    }

    private sealed class DynamicCloseableDescriptor : IDisposable
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo OpenGenericDelegateMethod;

        static DynamicCloseableDescriptor()
        {
            OpenGenericDelegateMethod = typeof(DialogContainer)
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(x => x.Name == "DynamicCloseDialog")
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        readonly object Target;
        readonly Type ICloseableType = null;
        readonly Delegate DynamicDelegate = null;
        readonly EventInfo DialogCloseEvent = null;
        readonly Type DialogResultType = null;

        public DynamicCloseableDescriptor(DialogContainer container, object target, Type iCloseableType)
        {
            if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            if (target == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
            if (iCloseableType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("iCloseableType");

            Target = target;
            ICloseableType = iCloseableType;

            DialogResultType = ICloseableType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            DialogCloseEvent = ICloseableType.GetEvent("DialogClose");

            DynamicDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                DialogCloseEvent.EventHandlerType,
                container,
                OpenGenericDelegateMethod.MakeGenericMethod(DialogResultType)
                );

            DialogCloseEvent.AddEventHandler(Target, DynamicDelegate);
        }

        public void ExecuteCancelIfCan()
        {
            if (IsDisposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("DynamicCloseableDescriptor");

            var cmd = ((ICancelable)Target).CancelCommand;

            if (cmd != null)
            {
                if (cmd.CanExecute(null))
                {
                    cmd.Execute(null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DynamicDelegate.DynamicInvoke(new[] { Target, null });
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private bool IsDisposed = false;

        private void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (!IsDisposed && isDisposing)
            {
                DialogCloseEvent.RemoveEventHandler(Target, DynamicDelegate);
                IsDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    internal object DialogContainerResult = null;


    /// <summary>
    /// Вызывается когда IDialogCloseable запускает DialogCloseEvent.
    /// Вызов этого метода строится динамически в DynamicCloseableDescriptor
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="sender">Event Sender</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event args</param>
    private void DynamicCloseDialog<T>(object sender, DialogCloseEventArgs<T> e)
    {
        if (CloseableDescriptor != null)
        {
            CloseableDescriptor.Dispose();
            CloseableDescriptor = null;
        }

        if (e != null)
        {
            if (e.DialogResult == true)
            {
                DialogContainerResult = e.Result;
            }

            this.DialogResult = e.DialogResult;
        }
        else
        {
            this.DialogResult = false;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CloseableDescriptor == null)
        {
            base.OnClosing(e);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)CloseableDescriptor.ExecuteCancelIfCan);
        }
    }
}


public static class DialogHelper
{
    public static void SendOk<T>(this DialogCloseEvent<T> handler, object sender, T result)
    {
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, DialogCloseEventArgs<T>.Success(result));
        }
    }

    public static void SendCancel<T>(this DialogCloseEvent<T> handler, object sender)
    {
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, DialogCloseEventArgs<T>.Cancel());
        }
    }
}


public class DialogCloseEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public bool? DialogResult { get; private set; }
    public T Result { get; private set; }

    public DialogCloseEventArgs(bool? dialogResult, T result)
    {
        DialogResult = dialogResult;
        Result = result;
    }

    private static readonly DialogCloseEventArgs<T> CancelResult;
    static DialogCloseEventArgs()
    {
        CancelResult = new DialogCloseEventArgs<T>(false, default(T));
    }

    public static DialogCloseEventArgs<T> Success(T result)
    {
        return new DialogCloseEventArgs<T>(true, result);
    }

    public static DialogCloseEventArgs<T> Cancel()
    {
        return CancelResult;
    }
}



//public delegate void DialogCloseEvent<in T>(bool dialogResult, T result);
/// <summary>
/// Запрос на закрытие диалога
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип возвращаемого результата</typeparam>
/// <param name="sender">Отправитель</param>
/// <param name="e">Результат диалога, по умолчанию - null = Cancel</param>
public delegate void DialogCloseEvent<T>(object sender, DialogCloseEventArgs<T> e = null);

public interface ICancelable
{
    ICommand CancelCommand { get; }
}

public interface IDialogCloseable<T> : ICancelable
{
    event DialogCloseEvent<T> DialogClose;
}
```