# Реализация открытия дочернего окна и передача данных в него при использование паттерна MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый вечер. Возник такой вопрос каким образом можно реализовать открытие дочернего окна `SecondView` из родительского `FirstView` и с привязанным к данному типу окна передать `SecondViewModel` этого окна, а так же передать какие либо параметры из родительской `MainViewModel` в дочернее и при закрытии отправить обратно в родительское `MainViewModel`.

Comment: Слышал что надо использовать Services, но не уверен что данный подход является наилучшим. Может не прав.

Comment: KJfe прав. Следует использовать сервисы. Если будет время вечером расскажу подробнее.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Открытие второго окна в паттерне MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742351/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5-mvvm)

Comment: И ещё один возможный дубликат: [Сервис создания модальных и немодальных окон в контексте паттерна MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525998/10105).

Comment: Вот что мне не нравиться во всякого рода паттернах так это возникающее на их основе фанатичные и бестолковые, с точки зрения рациональности, надуманные ограничения, которые ведут в свою очередь к бесполезным и сложным решениям. Яркими примерами коих как раз и есть эти тонны бесполезного кода ссылки на которые дали в своих комментах @tym32167 и VladD.

Comment: Сперва я создавал дочернее окно с помощью создания экземпляра `View` и привязки к нему экземпляр ViewModel` через `DataContext`
т.е. в `MainViewModel` срабатывал метод открытия нового окна 
и происходило  SecondView secondView = new SecondView(); secondView = new SecondViewModel(); seconViewModel.ShowDialog(); но была проблема передачи данных во внутрь и обратно как вариант можно было бы через делегат перекидывать.

Comment: Создайте интерфейс с объявлением метода, с помощью которого вы будете открывать дочер.окна. Реализуйте метод в кодбихайнд главного окна, параметр этого метода можно сделать  `enum`. В методе будете сначала создавать инстанс вьюмодели, затем переменным вьюмодели будете  передавать данные, дальше создаете инстанс дочернего окна, далее делаете привязку вьюмодели к `DataContext` окна, далее показываете дочернее окно. Во вьюмодель через его конструктор будете передавать экз. глав. окна, через тип интерфейса. Т. образом из вьюмодели глав.окна можно вызывать метод для показа дочер.окна.

Comment: @Bulson Я скинул ссылку на похожий вопрос. Если вы видите, как улучшить те ответы - улучшайте. А про ограничения я не понял. Паттерны существуют, чтобы решать конкретные задачи. Если они задачи не решают - значит они не подходят в текущей ситуации. Если решают - то подходят.

Comment: @tym32167 все так. Но, вот касательно MVVM самым ярким примером, того о чем я говорил это сентенции вроде этой: "кодбихайнд не должно быть не строчки кода, все нужно делать только через привязки, конвертеры, команды, поведения.". Слепое следование этому ограничению ведет к тоннам и тоннам бесполезного кода, когда эта же проблема порой решается парой строк в кодбихайнд, но ведь это нельзя! Это преступно! Вот о чем я.

Comment: @Bulson так это не про паттерны совсем. Есть такое, когда для хелловорлда вкручивают PRISM - это типичная проблема. Также часто видишь, когда одну и ту же вещь в большом проекте реализуют 100500 способами (кому как удобно), а все от того, что не было гайдлайнов как это делать, так и плодится портянка лапшеговнокода. И потом садишься и смотришь, как умники реализовали свой тред пул, который используется через раз, а джуны нахреначили стили прямо в страницы xaml копипастой, и все они уже уволились, а тебе это поддерживать.

Comment: @tym32167 ага! Значит и вы наступали в это г.... :) Я уже здесь как то отвечал на подобный вопрос, только там было про переключение страниц во фрейме, а не вызов окон, но это практически похоже. Автор вопроса, как в прочем большинство здесь, почему-то не воспользовался поиском по сайту.

Comment: @Bulson Я в это не просто наступал, я в этом плавал на подлодке, почитывая Фаулера и гайдлайны :)