# Программное связывание view и viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как организовать (при нажатии определённого пункта меню) погрузку view и соответствующих им viewmodel во frame? В проекте используется wpf, стараюсь придерживаться mvvm. Проект состоит из множества страниц, которые надо подгружать во frame в главном окне программы. Буду благодарна за любую помощь. Может направите в сторону нужных источников информации.

Comment: Какой язык программирования используете? C# или F#?

Comment: если хотите следовать паттерну `MVVM` то скорее всего придется отказаться от`Frame`

Comment: Использую язык программирования C#

Comment: тогда советую добавить эту метку - ее просматривают больше людей чем просто `wpf`

Comment: Спасибо. Добавила.

Comment: На самом деле такой вопрос постоянно поднимается: [Отображение разного содержимого в одном окне WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763691/Отображение-разного-содержимого-в-одном-окне-wpf-mvvm)

Comment: если сможете разобраться по ответу который там дан, то предлагаю закрыть как дубликат

Comment: если нет, то будем разбираться

Comment: Для навигации во Frame используется NavigationService, но он оперирует с Page, VM же не должна знать ничего о представлении, поэтому вам нужно написать свою обертку над штатным сервисом навигации, которая будет оперировать уже с VM. Что-то похожее было здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525998/218063