# Как правильно предать datacontext из одного окна в другое

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем здравствуйте, встала проблема, в моем приложении в датагрид есть данные, при клике на строку я открываю новое окно, но  как сделать правильно в рамках mvvm, чтобы передать в новое окно контекст, мне нужно просто отобразить в новом окне данные из выделенной в датагрид строке. Не хочу делать новую `viewModel` для нового окна.

Вот команда открытия окна:

```
public Comand OpenWindow
{
    get
    {
        return new Comand(async () =>
        {
            // это свойство выделеннйостроки
                var ss = CurrentItem;

                VakansNAME = ((Resume)ss).VacansName;

                var Forotpmp = ((Resume)ss).Foto;
            // получаю фото
                FOTO= await justDo.GetFoto(Forotpmp);
            // открываю новое окно
            var window =new Window1();
            window.Show();

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: `var window =new Window1(); window.DataContext = {ваш datacontext};`?

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за ответ, а вот вопрос,мой datacontext какой, если эту команду я вызываю из моей ViewModel, то есть мне как то вызывать свой датаконтекст получается?

Comment: Если ваша вьюмодель - этот тот объект, который вы хотите передать как контекст, то `window.DataContext = this;`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сервис создания модальных и немодальных окон в контексте паттерна MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525998/218063)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ваша ссылка очень полезная, но дубликат ли это? ведь вопрос о передаче контекста, а не о открытии новых окон

Comment: @АндрейNOP не дубликат вопроса,спасибо за ответ. Вопрос в связи датаконтекста и viewmodel при случае открытии нового окна

Comment: @tym32167, если бы был однозначный дубликат — я бы ударил молотом :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP окей )

Comment: Ну и, конечно, VM не должна явно создавать и открывать окно. А должен делать это сервис создания окон, на который я дал ссылку :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP скажем так, многое в представленном коде вызывает вопросы (например, зачем каждый раз при обращении создавать команду)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Vm в моем случае реализует команду для открытия окна и все. То есть идет команда окно открывается, Просто  если в winforms я бы просто передал в конструктор окна нужные мне данные и все,а тут вот загвоздка

Comment: В чем загвоздка? Я вас не понимаю. Я вам говорю про то, что VM не должна знать про GUI и тем более явно создавать его части

Comment: @АндрейNOP а как я без команды открою, у меня во view по вашему же методу привязана команда.

Comment: С помощью сервиса, например, как в приведенной ссылке. В прочем, делайте так как считаете нужным, я просто дал ссылку, которая может оказаться полезной вам или тому, кто будет читать вопрос в дальнейшем.

Comment: @АндрейNOP VM оперирует свойствами, к которым привязана View, я и пытаюсь сделать нужные мне свойства, командой вызвать открытие окна и предать в него то,что хочу отобразить, или я методологически не прав?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ваша ссылка хорошая, я пока не могу точно понять ее алгоритм, но пробовать буду, то есть вы полагаете,что открытие любых окон, лучше делать так,как вы указали в ссылке? А вызывать мне это открытие как? Опять же вопрос с контекстом

Comment: Там есть пример использования, создайте пустой проект и попробуйте его, разберите. Если вы используете какой-то MVVM-фреймворк, то в нем скорее всего есть что-то подобное в комплекте. Почитайте документацию. Ну а по сути ЭТОГО вопроса вам уже выше ответили.

Comment: У вас в переменной ss уже есть информация о выбранной строке, если фото не нужно передавать в открываемое окно, то вы можете сделать вот так: window.DataContext = ss; А если фотов открываемом окне нужно, то и получать вы его можете в нем.