# Окно с критериями для фильтра основной таблицы

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть главное окно, содержащее таблицу. Есть вспомогательное окно, содержащее критерии для фильтра главной таблицы.

Как правильно организовать данную логику в рамках wpf и mvvm?

То есть получается есть MainViewModel, есть FilterViewModel. Необходимо из MainViewModel запустить FilterViewModel с ссылкой на MainViewModel. В MainViewModel необходимо иметь ссылку на некий объект, содержащий в себе критерии для фильтра. При обновлении критериев во FilterViewModel необходимо обновлять данный объект и через ссылку на MainViewModel вызывать refresh у таблицы. В MainViewModel тоже должна быть ссылка на FilterViewModel, что бы контролировать количество открытых окон с фильтром (не больше 1).

Правильны ли данные рассуждения?

Вопрос: учитывая, что окно с фильтром должно быть открыто максимум в единственном экземпляре, то как в mvvm это контролировать? То есть при закрытии FilterViewModel необходимо стирать на него ссылку у MainViewModel. Как?

Для открытия окно используется сервис на подобии описанного [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525998/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0-mvvm).

Comment: Почему окно, а не просто `<Popup>`? Который можно прятать, можно показывать. То, что вы описали, не похоже на окно.

Comment: Вы можете иметь и разные модели (для фильтрации и данных), а можете на оба окна натянуть одну и ту же модель, все от вас зависит. Работать будет и так и так.