# c# WPF Как передать данных из одного окна в другое

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, popup

Доброго времени суток господа эксперты. Подскажите  пожалуйста новичку в WPF. В главном окне есть кнопка открытия диалогового окна формы. Как после заполнения полей вернуть эти данные в главное окно для последующего сохранения в бд и обновления списка? Не смог найти подходящей реализации. Ниже  код приложения. Сразу не кидайте  палки и камни, код приложения тестовый  поэтому здесь сумбур, создал для понимания процесса из него  буду собирать  нормальное , когда приведу в порядок  все операции CRUD.Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Главное окно RecordsWindowView

```
 public partial class RecordsWindowView : Window
{
    public RecordsWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new RecordsViewModel();
    }
}
```

Вьюмоделька:

```
 public class RecordsViewModel : ViewModelBase
```

{

```
   private Article _selectedRecord; 
    public Article SelectedRecord
    {
        get { return _selectedRecord; }
        set
        {
            _selectedRecord = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRecord");
        }
    }          

    public RecordsViewModel()
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        using (AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var listRecords = context.News.ToList();
            _records = new ObservableCollection<Article>(listRecords);
        }
    }
private ObservableCollection<Article> _records { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Article> Records
    {
        get { return _records; }
        set
        {
            _records = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CollectionCar");
        }
    }
  private ICommand _addNewItemCommand;
    public ICommand AddNewItemCommand =>
   _addNewItemCommand ?? (_addNewItemCommand = new MyCommand(AddFormRecord));
  

      private async void AddFormRecord(object obj)
    {
       
        
        AddFormView addRecordWindow = new AddFormView();
      
        if (addRecordWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
        {               
            var newRecord = (AddFormVM)addRecordWindow.DataContext;                            
            using (AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                await context.News.AddAsync(newRecord.Record);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
        }
    }
```

}

Диалоговое окно формы:

```
public partial class AddFormView : Window
{
  //  public Article Record { get;  set; }
    public AddFormView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Record = rec;
        //DataContext = Record;
        DataContext = new AddFormVM ();
    }
   
 

    private void Accept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }

}
```

Вторая вьюмодель:

```
public class AddFormVM : ViewModelBase
{
   
    private Article _record;
    public Article Record
    {
        get { return _record; }
        set
        {
            _record = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRecord");
        }
    }
}
```

Базовая модель:

```
  public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        // PropertyChanged получает свойство из окна xlm какогото поля и обновляет  событие
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Главное окно со списком записей:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppTEST_dot_NET5_ICommand_SQL.Views.RecordsWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppTEST_dot_NET5_ICommand_SQL.Views"
    xmlns:vmodels="clr-namespace:WpfAppTEST_dot_NET5_ICommand_SQL.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="RecordsWindowView" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
  
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>            
        
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   
    <Grid Grid.Row="0"  > 
   
        <DataGrid                     
            ItemsSource="{Binding  Records, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            IsReadOnly="True"
            
            >
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*"  Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ArticleId}" FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" />
                <DataGridTextColumn   Width="*"  Header="TITLE" Binding="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" />
                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*"  Header="TITLE" Binding="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" />
                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*"   Header="DECRIPTION" Binding="{Binding Descripton}" FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" />
                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*"  Header="CATEGORY" Binding="{Binding Category}" FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" />
                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="*"  Header="AUTHOR" Binding="{Binding Author}" FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="*"  Header="ACTIONS">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           
                                <Button 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"  
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Content="DELETE"/>
                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>               
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Диалоговое окно формы:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppTEST_dot_NET5_ICommand_SQL.Views.AddFormView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppTEST_dot_NET5_ICommand_SQL.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="AddFormView" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Margin="10" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding Record}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>


        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Название" />
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Record.Title}" />
        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Описание" />
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Record.Descripton}" />
        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Полный текст" />
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Record.FullText}" />
        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Категирия" />
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Record.Category}" />
        <TextBlock  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Автор" />
        <TextBox  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Record.Author}" />
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button  IsDefault="True" Click="Accept_Click" MinWidth="60" Margin="5">OK</Button>
            <Button IsCancel="True" MinWidth="60" Margin="5">Отмена</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что у вас нету MVVM. У вас окно отвечает за VM слой, создает его, управляет сроком жизни и т.д., когда по правилам MVVM, View слой должен быть **максимально** отделен от других, оно не должно знать, что где-то там есть некий класс, в котором свойство ..., из которого надо взять данные. Также и наоборот, VM слой не должен знать что-либо о View, он должен лишь взять данные из Model, сделать нужные свойства для привязки, все. Ну и также, вы делаете `Click`, что тоже в MVVM не есть хорошо, ибо все события там на `ICommand`. MVVM - это абстракции и минимальная связь всего.

Comment: Ну а так, если хотите ваш код заставить работать, то после строки `AddFormView addRecordWindow = new AddFormView();` сделайте `addRecordWindow.DataContext = ...;`, а из конструктора уберите, само значение `DataContext` вынесите в отдельное свойство, к которому будете иметь доступ, ну и дальше дергайте из нее что хотите. Ну либо сделайте метод, который вернет вам результат (а-ля `var result = addRecordWindow.DoSome();`, но это я думаю понимаете, что все является костылями. Ну а примерно [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/220553) у вас должно быть.

Comment: Извините, но я вас не совсем понял. У меня за логику отвечают 2 VM (RecordsViewModel  и AddFormVM) . Их я и передам в контекст в конструкторе  окон AddFormView и RecordsWindowView. В коде окон у меня никакой логики нет, ну кроме клика в диалоговом. Не могли бы вы показать пример правильной реализации mvvm  и передачи данных между окнами.

Comment: `У меня за логику отвечают 2 VM` - да, а кто отвечает за эти VM? Кто их создает? Помним правило MVVM, где "View слой не должен знать про VM и М, а VM не должен знать про View", нарушено ли оно у вас? Вот если к примеру удалить класс `RecordsViewModel`, запустится ли приложение с пустым UI? Нет. Почему? А потому, что оно тесно связано с этим классом. Почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). `Не могли бы вы показать` - так я вроде уже показал, не?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ, попытаюсь все поправить на основе ваших рекомендаций.