# Авторизация в рамках MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В своем проекте (WPF) я создал главное окно MainWindow, которое является точкой входа в программу. Однако, прежде чем отобразить его, нужно реализовать авторизацию во вспомогательном окне AuthWindow

Привязка данных и алгоритм авторизации работают исправно, однако переключение между окнами и корректная последовательность их отображения - непосильная задача для меня уже на протяжении пары дней

Во вспомогательном классе мне удалось реализовать показ нового окна. В упрощенном виде этот метод выглядит так:

```
public static void ShowAuthWindow(string aWindowName)
{
    Type vType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                         .GetTypes()
                         .FirstOrDefault(t => String.Compare(t.Name, aWindowName) == 0);
    if (vType != null)
    {
        if (Activator.CreateInstance(vType) is Window vResult)
            vResult.Show();
    }
}
```

Хотя, как мне кажется, это все же идет вразрез с принципами MVVM, т. к. параметр - название окна - жестко прописывается во viewmodel

Возможно, есть более элегантное решение этой проблемы, учитывая, что многооконные приложения не такая редкость. Буду признателен, если кому-то удастся навести на правильную мысль =)

Comment: Посмотрите ответ
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/388657,
возможно поможет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы не использовать IoC контейнер в таком случае? Ведь вы на этапе разработки точно знаете, какой именно тип окна надо показать первым, так почему бы это не указать явно? Какая разница, передавать тип строчкой или готовым типом? С точки зрения проектирования, я не вижу разницы.

Вы верно подметили, VM не должна управлять окнами, UI должен решать какие данные в каком окне и с какими контролами надо отображать, но точка входа все равно указывается явно в точке сборки приложения - Composition Root, там и стартует главное окно (не важно какое именно).

Пример:

- [Навигация в приложении, с частичной сменой View](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1266044/373567)

Если у вас перед показом основного UI нужно отобразить окно логина, то так и напишите в коде. Смысл заворачивания абстракций в том чтобы была гибкость в разработке. Чем меньше связаны между собой компоненты приложения - тем легче их разрабатывать не ломая связи. Об этом, как мне кажется и говорить MVVM и прочие шаблоны.

Попробуйте действительно передать управление экземплярами окон в IoC контейнер, оберните его в фабрику окошек и пусть она по типу VM будет вам нужное окно выдавать, там же можно и смапить пары VM-View.

```
WindowFactory.Instance.Display<LoginViewModel>();
```

Как-то так я это вижу. Эта фабрика и будет развязкой для колбэков из VM во View. Далее уже вам решать, нужны ли вам только пары или нужно несколько вьюх на одну VM или наоборот.

---

*Кстати, `string` это `sealed` класс, можно не опасаться, что кто-то вам поломает операции сравнения строк полиморфизмом. `str1 == str2` выглядит намного лучше, чем констркукция `string.Compare` в вашем случае. Есть еще `.Equals` и несколько других вариантов, возвращающих `bool`.*