# Как отобразить окно сохранения если пользователь что-то изменил и пытается закрыть окно соответствуя MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

1. Закрывать окно можно разными способами и я считаю, что нужно ловить Closing событие и там вызвать ICommand.Execute чтобы показать окно подтверждения. Т.е. делать свое кастомное Window?
2. Трекинг изменений свойств делать в ViewModel или есть другие пути? XAML?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/220553

Answer (score 1):

В вашем сценарии нет ничего необычного. Все решается типичными средствами MVVM. Событие окна `Closed` обрабатывается командой (так же, как и любое другое событие). Показать диалог можно двумя способами: либо послать сообщение во *View* (что проще всего), либо использовать типичную для MVVM абстракцию *View Service*. Начнем с первого способа.

Событие можно пробросить в команду с помощью библиотеки *Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf* (раньше она входила в состав Blend, теперь это отдельный NuGet пакет) следующим образом:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWpfApp"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Обратите внимание на атрибут `PassEventArgsToCommand`. Он отвечает за проброс аргумента события `Closing` в команду, где мы затем сможем его обработать.

В примере ниже я использую библиотеку *CommunityToolkit.Mvvm*, но для других MVVM фреймворков код будет очень похожим.

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ClosingCommand = new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(OnClosing);
    }

    public IRelayCommand<CancelEventArgs> ClosingCommand { get; }

    private void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs args)
    {
        // TODO: Display dialog and process CancelEventArgs.
    }
}
```

Теперь нам нужно написать обработчик команды, который попросит *View* показать диалог закрытия приложения, при этом, естественно, не ссылаясь на *View* напрямую. Для этого я создал очень простой DTO класс `DialogMessage` с двумя свойствами – `Text` и `Result`, который использую в качесве сообщения. Сообщение отправим с помощью *Messenger* (это типичный паттерн *Publish-Subscribe*), который предоставляет библиотека MVVM.

```
private void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs args)
{
    var message = WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(
        new DialogMessage("Do you really want to close the app?"));

    if (message.Result)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Осталось обработать сообщение во *View*. Сделать это можно примерно так:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(this, (_, message) =>
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show(this, message.Text, Title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        message.Result = result == MessageBoxResult.OK;
    });
}
```

Если вам нужны cложные сценарии взаимодействия со *View*, то *View Service* может оказаться более гибким решением. По сути это паттерн *Dependency Inversion*, где реальный *View* скрывается за абстракцией (интерфейсом). Ниже пример реализации для диалога. *View Model* получит ссылку на `IDialogService` через конструктор (обычно это делается с помощью *DI* контейнера):

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public bool ShowDialog(string message, string title)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        return result == MessageBoxResult.OK;
    }
}
```

При этом *View Service* может выполнять сколь угодно сложные манипуляции с окном или контролами, такие как старт анимации, отображение окон, системных диалогов, нотификаций, закрытие приложения, и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

**Как бы я поступил:**

1. Я бы не советовал оставлять все на самотек. Лучше делать проверку по закрытию окна.
2. Изменения можно ловить во ViewModel. Я ввожу свойство IsDirty.

**И так, к коду:**

1. Модель:

   ```
    public class Foo : BaseModel
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }
   ```

где:

- BaseModel унаследован от INotifyPropertyChanged (мне так удобнее, тут вам решать)
- SetProperty:

```
protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T lastValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
{
    if (Equals(newValue, lastValue))
        return false;
    lastValue = newValue;
    OnPropertyChanged(prop);
    return true;
}
```

2. ViewModel

   ```
    public class FooViewModel : BaseViewModel<Foo>
    {
        public string Name { get => Model.Name; set => Model.Name = value; }

        private bool _isDirty;
        // Тут свойство изменений
        public bool IsDirty { get => _isDirty; set => SetProperty(ref _isDirty, value); }

        public FooViewModel(Foo model) : base(model)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(prop);
            IsDirty = true;
        }

        // Если нужно закрыть окно 
        private RelayCommand _cmdClose;
        public RelayCommand CmdClose =>
            _cmdClose ??= new RelayCommand(n => WindowRegistry.Close(this));
    }
   ```
3. Базовая модель ViewModel

   ```
    public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public T Model { get; }

        public BaseViewModel2(T model)
        {
            Model = model;
            if (model is INotifyPropertyChanged bm)
            {
                bm.PropertyChanged += Bm_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        // транзит от Model
        private void Bm_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            => OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName));

        protected bool SetProperty<Tp>(ref Tp lastValue, Tp newValue, [CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (Equals(newValue, lastValue))
                return false;
            lastValue = newValue;
            OnPropertyChanged(prop);
            return true;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
   ```
4. Регистрация окон

   ```
    public static class WindowRegistry
    {
        static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> WindowsBase = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
        static readonly Dictionary<object, Window> LoadWindows = new Dictionary<object, Window>();

        public static void RegisterWindow<T, W>()
            where W : Window, new()
            where T : class
        {
            WindowsBase[typeof(T)] = typeof(W);
        }

        static Window CreateWindow(object viewModel)
        {
            Type windowType = null;

            var vmType = viewModel.GetType();

            while (vmType != null && !WindowsBase.TryGetValue(vmType, out windowType))
                vmType = vmType.BaseType;

            if (windowType == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"Запрашиваемое окно не зарегестрированно в базе {viewModel.GetType().FullName}");

            var window = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(windowType);
            window.DataContext = viewModel;
            return window;
        }


        static void Add(object viewModel, Window wnd)
        {
            while (LoadWindows.Any(n => n.Value.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed))
                LoadWindows.Remove(LoadWindows.First(n => n.Value.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed).Key);

            LoadWindows.Add(viewModel, wnd);
        }


        #region Синхронный вызов
        public static void Show(object viewModel)
        {
            var window = CreateWindow(viewModel);
            Add(viewModel, window);
            window.Show();
        }

        public static void ShowDialog(object viewModel)
        {
            var window = CreateWindow(viewModel);

            if (LoadWindows.Count > 0)
            {
                window.Owner = LoadWindows.Last().Value;
            }
            else
            {
                window.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            }

            Add(viewModel, window);
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            window.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => window.ShowDialog());
            LoadWindows.Remove(viewModel);
        }

        public static void Hide(object viewModel)
        {
            if (!LoadWindows.TryGetValue(viewModel, out var wnd))
                return;
            wnd.Hide();
        }
        public static void Visible(object viewModel)
        {
            if (!LoadWindows.TryGetValue(viewModel, out var wnd))
                return;
            wnd.Show();
        }
        #endregion

        public static async Task ShowDialogAsync(object viewModel)
        {
            var window = CreateWindow(viewModel);

            if (LoadWindows.Count > 0)
            {
                window.Owner = LoadWindows.Last().Value;
            }
            else
            {
                window.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            }

            Add(viewModel, window);
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            await window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => window.ShowDialog());
            LoadWindows.Remove(viewModel);
        }

        public static void Close(object viewModel)
        {
            if (LoadWindows.TryGetValue(viewModel, out var window))
            {
                window.Close();
                LoadWindows.Remove(viewModel);
            }
        }
    }
   ```
5. Регистрация в App:

   ```
    WindowRegistry.RegisterWindow<FooViewModel, FooView>();
   ```
6. Ну и открытие окна, с контролем изменения и сохранением:

   ```
        private RelayCommand _cmdOpenWindow;
        public RelayCommand CmdOpenWindow =>
            _cmdOpenWindow ??= new RelayCommand(async n =>
            {
                if (n is not FooViewModel foo)
                    return;

                await WindowRegistry.ShowDialogAsync(foo);
                if (foo.IsDirty) // + проверки на правильное закрытие окна - тут сами
                {
                    Model.Save(foo.Model);
                }
            });
   ```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134407/discussion-on-answer-by-fapser-faps------).