# Как оповестить пользователя программы о некорректном вводе WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть следующая вью модель, в `SaveSettingsChangesCommand` выкидываю исключение если ввод некорректный, но как мне об этом оповестить пользователя? Говорят добавлять `MessageBox` во `ViewModel`'и - плохо, но как по другому? Делать отдельное окно и вьюмодель под него и регистрировать (как говорилось в первой части вот [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/422180) ответа)?

```
public class InboundCheckerSettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly InboundCheckerSettings _settings;
   
    private int _delay;
    private DateTime _start;

    public int Delay { get => _delay; set => SetProperty(ref _delay, value); }
    public DateTime Start { get => _start; set => SetProperty(ref _start, value); }

   
   public InboundCheckerSettingsViewModel()
   {
      _settings = StaticApplication.Service.Resolve<Settings>().InboundCheckerSettings;
      Delay = _settings.Delay;
      Start = _settings.Start;
   }

   public ICommand SaveSettingsChangesCommand
   {
        get => new Command((_) =>
        {
            if(Delay <= 0)
               throw new ArgumentException();

            _settings.Delay = Delay;
            _settings.Start = Start;
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: ну да, делать сервис диалоговых окон, как, например, вот тут - https://youtu.be/OLaOmRwP2II

Comment: В WPF, при правильной привязке и с хорошем стилем (стандартный например), любое неверное значение (например строка в int) приведет к выделению элемента красной рамкой, а сама привязка не обновится. Также вы можете на основе этого сделать свои правила, все это делается через [ValidationRules](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation). Так что, есть ли смысл на каждый чих выводить пользователю диалоговое окно? Меня бы такое раздражало.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы правы, спасибо. Это действительно лучше, чем диалоговые окна