# Как правильно закрывать окна в WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Открывать окна я научился благодаря [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525998/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0-mvvm). Однако, закрывать окна правильно тоже нужно и для этого есть метод `HidePresentation` (см. в ответе по ссылке выше), но где мне вызывать этот метод? В овете есть пример закрытия, но это не то, что мне нужно, поскольку окна надо будет закрывать мышкой, а не в результате выполнения какого-то метода. У меня есть только два способа которые я придумал себе:

1. Создать обработчик события `Closing` для самого окна и в нем вызвать метод `HidePresentation`
2. Указать `WindowStyle = "None"`, самостоятельно сделать кнопку закрытия и повесить на `ICommand` в которой так же вызывать метод `HidePresentation`.

Я сейчас придерживаюсь первого варианта поскольку для меня он намного проще, но честно говоря я так же сомневаюсь в этом способе, но не знаю почему. Так как же правильно закрывать окна для WPF с MVVM?

Comment: `Как правильно закрывать окна в WPF MVVM?` мышкой на крестик, либо окно должно само себя закрывать, когда поймет что больше не нужно. Централизованного управления быть не должно.

Comment: @aepot а зачем мне тогда контролировать открыто ли окно?

Comment: Используйте `Closing`. Операции с View должны быть во View, утаскивать их в VM слой ради того чтобы просто утаскивать - не стоит.

Comment: @Aarnihauta ` а зачем мне тогда контролировать открыто ли окно?` - а это все зависит от того, что именно вам надо и в каком виде. Многие проекты делают так, что при закрытии диалога, возвращается некий калбек, некое событие о том, что окно закрылось, внутри которого содержится тип закрытия (крестик, по кнопке, программно например) и необходимые возвращаемые свойства. Ну а для того, чтоб это все сделать, нужно конечно событие закрытия. Я вам советую посмотреть [это видео](https://youtu.be/S8hEjLahNtU), где автор библиотеки Prism рассказывает базовый принцип диалогов, включая их закрытие.