# Как отобразить данные в TextBox из DataContext?

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, model-view

Имеется класс CardModel

```
class CardModel : ObservableObject 
    {
        private string _sh;

        public string Sh
        {
            get { return _sh; }
            set { _sh = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _equip;

        public string Equip
        {
            get { return _equip; }
            set { _equip = value; }
        }


        public CardModel()
        {
                        
        }

    }
```

Имеется форма Card, на ней есть TextBox, который биндит Sh:

```
<TextBox x:Name="testTB" Text="{Binding Path=Sh, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="30" Margin="481,20,-279,380" FontSize="20"/>
```

У формы есть DataContext

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local1:CardModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Когда форма открывается, в неё передается sh типа long. И если в инициализации формы написать textbox.text = sh.ToString(); то все работает. Но это неправильно. Я хочу, чтобы textbox биндил данные из DataConext. Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
public Window1(long sh)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new CardModel();
            CardModel card = new CardModel();
            card.Sh = sh.ToString();
        }
```

Но textbox'у вообще пофигу. Но если запустить цикл с перезаписью переменной внутри CardModel, то textbox вообще с радостью все будет отображать.

Так вот вопрос: как, следуя паттерну MVVM сделать так, чтобы при открытии новой формы, в которую передается инфо с родительской формы, эта информация отображалась в textbox

Comment: Когда вы пишете `<local1:CardModel/>` - вам создает View слой за вас этот класс, инициализируя его значениями по умолчанию. Когда вы делаете `= new CardModel()` - каждый раз, когда вы пишете `new`, вы делаете **новый** класс, который не связан каким-либо образом со старым, он имеет свой набор данных. Вот в вашем вопросе 3 экземпляра класса `CardModel`, когда должен быть один. Условно, последний ваш код должен быть таким: `var card = new CardModel(); DataContext = card; card.Sh = sh;`, как видите, один класс. НО, это нарушение MVVM, ибо View слой не должен знать ничег о про другие слои.

Comment: Как и `<Window.DataContext>` - это тоже [нарушение MVVM](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). В подходе MVVM окна, это довольно запутанная тема, ибо это View слой, а вы не можете его взять и сделать `new Windows().Show()`, ибо правила MVVM гласят "Слои не должны знать друг о друге", то есть V не должен знать о VM/M, а VM/M не должны знать о V, ну и M не должен знать о VM/V. А когда вы так инициализируете окно, вы явно, в VM/M слое делаете V. Тут должна быть абстрактная прослойка, некий сервис, который по VM слою откроет вам окно и сам задаст `DataContext`.

Comment: Во, про окна вспомнил [ответ один хороший](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/220553). Обратите внимание на `var askCloseVM = new AskVM("Do you want to close the application?");` - то есть, для окна делается обертка, с ее VM, благодаря которой уже и открывается окно. Нету такого, что в VM слое создается объект V слоя, есть простая работа с ViewModel, не более. Вот это MVVM.

Comment: Ничего не понял, но сделаю. По первому комментарию - да, в обход mvvm, но получилось добиться так, как вы описали. Второй - буду гуглить и седеть, постараюсь придумать как это выстроить. По третьему, спасибо за ссылку, изучу) А вообще большое спасибо за большой комментарий)