# Использование MessageBox отдельным классом в WPF приложениях

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Я не хочу просто использовать MessageBox внутри методов, потому что иногда (из-за довольно больших сообщений) читабельность кода ухудшается, я бы хотел вынести свои MessageBox в какое нибудь отдельное место и доставать нужный мне MessageBox, когда мне он понадобится. Как это правильнее сделать? Все до чего я додумался - это создать статичный класс со статичными методами. Вот пример:

```
public static class NoticeService {
  public static void EmptyEmployeeCodeError() {
    MessageBox.Show("Empty code", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
  }

  public static void InvalidEmployeeCodeError() {
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid code", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
  }

  public static MessageBoxResult DeleteApplicationDialog() {
    return MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this application", "Dialog",
      MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
  }

  public static MessageBoxResult LogoutEmployeeDialog() {
    return MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to log out", "Dialog", MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
      MessageBoxImage.Question);
  }
}
```

Но мне кажется, что это не очень хорошее решение. Как мне переделать это?

Comment: Правильно - MVVM, где вы отделяете UI от данных, делите все на слои, которые мало связанны друг с другом. MVVM в свою очередь запрещает использовать UI элементы в коде, нужна абстракция поверх, сервис. Как сделать это [написано тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/220553). Так что, выбирайте, правильно вам, или тяп-ляп как сейчас.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я знаю про mvvm. Но разве использование mvvm в маленьких приложениях оправдано?
И вообще я не понимаю к чему ваш ответ. Может я не правильно задал вопрос, проще говоря я хочу убрать длинную строчку (а иногда и не одну) с MessageBox из методов, чтобы они не были такими громоздкими. То есть я хочу сделать примерно такое, только для MessageBox:
```private bool IsInputEmpty => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Input.Text);```
То есть я хочу сделать код более лаконичным. И вопрос в том, как лучше это сделать, с помощью статического класса или чего-нибудь другого.

Comment: Я не давал ответ, это комментарий, мы с вами просто общаемся. Использование MVVM есть смысл всегда, он упрощает жизнь в будущем. Вот я сейчас переписываю свой древний проект, там все без MVVM, знаете как я страдаю?) Если бы был MVVM, то мне пришлось бы всего 1 класс поменять, или даже один метод, а не пол проекта. "К чему ответ" - к тому, что правильно, по правилам MVVM, делать сервис, и потом просто делать по типу `var askCloseVM = new AskVM("Do you want to close the application?");`, вот и будет ваш диалог, с нужным текстом и результатом. Ну а статика - зло, советую забыть про нее.

Comment: `MessageBox` - неудобная штука, его непросто позиционировать, я настрадался во времена винформ. Для отладки норм, а вот как штатное средство, часть UI приложения - корявый инструмент. Напишите своё окно, но или вообще панелью прямо в текущем окне показывайте.